# Ellipse radius from center and point

Tags: geometry

[image: Image of problem]

Is there a way to get the radius of an ellipse, we know the center and one point on the ellipse, also we know that horizontal size is 2*r, vertical size is r. we also know angle alpha of point on ellipse and distance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the green point is angle $\alpha$ from the positive $x$-axis, measured counterclockwise, and that we place $(x_2, y_2)$ at the origin, the equation of the lower-right ellipse is 
$$
\left( \frac{x}{2r_2}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{r_2}\right)^2  = 1
$$
and the coordinates of the green point are 
$$
(u, v) = (2r_2 \cos \alpha, r_2 \sin \alpha)
$$
Since you claim to know the distance from this point to the center (I think you've labelled that "d", but it could be an "$\alpha$" -- hard to tell!), we then know that
\begin{align}
d^2 
&= (2 r_2 \cos \alpha)^2 + (r_2 \sin \alpha)^2\\
&= r_2^2\left[ (2 \cos \alpha)^2 + (\sin \alpha)^2\right]\\
&= r_2^2\left[ 4 \cos^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \alpha\right]\\
\end{align}
hence
\begin{align}
r_2^2 &= \frac{ 4 \cos^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \alpha}{d^2}\\
r_2 &= \sqrt{\frac{ 4 \cos^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \alpha}{d^2}}\\
\end{align}

That answers the question you asked in words; it doesn't seem to match what you've drawn in the picture, however, which involves both $r_1$ and $r_2$, and ... well, frankly, I have no idea what it could be about.